# has type unicode but expected one of :bytes tf.train.example

Tags: python, tensorflow, unicode

When I make tfrecords file , say unicode string is written, there will be an error:TypeError: u'\u634f' has type unicode but expected one of :bytes

`writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecords_output_filename)
text=u'地离开对方'
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={'text':_bytes_feature([text])}))
writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()`

But the English and the digital form is fine : text='abcd123'
How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have to encode text in utf-8 instead of unicode for it to be byte compatible :

```
text=u'地离开对方'
text = text.encode("utf8")
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={'text':_bytes_feature([text])}))
```